# preg_replace syntax (img src) and keeping part of the URL

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to do something similar to [preg_replace syntax (img src)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052948/preg-replace-syntax-img-src) but I don't want to take away everything in the SRC attribute.

```
src="http://www.bob.com/co/02/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/david_hasselhoff_at_the_dome_5.jpg"
```

I just want to replace the **`http://www0.bob.com/co/02/`**. It can vary.

So what I am trying to do is to replace what is between `src="` to `/wp-content/` in a image tag.

How can I go about this?

Here is the code I tried:

```
$content = preg_replace('!(?<=src\=\").+(?=\"(\s|\/\>))!', 'http://alex.com/wp-content/', $content);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use,

```
$str = 'src="http://www.bob.com/co/02/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/david_hasselhoff_at_the_dome_5.jpg"'; 

preg_replace("/(src=\")(.*)(\/wp-content)/", "$1http://example.com$3", $str);
```

Which would return,

```
src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/david_hasselhoff_at_the_dome_5.jpg"
```

---

**Greedy / Non-greedy**

The comment about `non-greedy` means that instead of using `(.*)` you could use `(.*?)`. The reason you would make it non-greedy is due to the fact that `(.*)` would match as much as it possibly can, for example if your string contained two image links:

```
$str = '<img src="http://www.bob.com/co/02/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/david_hasselhoff_at_the_dome_5.jpg" /> <img src="http://www.bob.com/co/02/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/david_hasselhoff_at_the_dome_5.jpg" />';
```

Then `(.*)`in the regex would match everything from the first "http://..." all the way until the second "/wp-content",

```
print_r(preg_replace("/(src=\")(.*)(\/wp-content)/", "$1http://example.com$3", $str));
                                ^^
```

This would then return `<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/david_hasselhoff_at_the_dome_5.jpg" />`

Using a non-greedy catch instead would yield this result,

```
print_r(preg_replace("/(src=\")(.*?)(\/wp-content)/", "$1http://example.com$3", $str));
                                ^^^ 
<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/david_hasselhoff_at_the_dome_5.jpg" /> <img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/david_hasselhoff_at_the_dome_5.jpg" />
```

Comment: I am unsure I follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to get the content until wp-content:

```
src="(.*)\/wp-content
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/jG5gM2/2)**

[image]

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [5-29]  `http://www.bob.com/co/02`
MATCH 2
1.  [98-113]    `http://alex.com`
```

Comment: @M42 thanks for the suggestion but saw that OP already marked the question as solved.